# web part footer does not appear

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

the web part footer does not appear in a webpart like this

```
<asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server" style="height:100px;" CssClass="PartZone" PartChromeType="TitleAndBorder" ShowTitleIcons="true" Width="200"> 
            <FooterStyle CssClass="PartFooterStyle" />
            <PartTitleStyle CssClass="PartTitleStyle" />

        <ZoneTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="200" Height="200">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"    />

            </asp:Panel>



        </ZoneTemplate>
        </asp:WebPartZone>
```

what is wrong with this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I believe it's a bug cause it does not appear at any condition.